# Is there a different test to check stationarity?

Tags: stationarity, statistical-finance

I am using the KPSS test to check stationarity of a financial time series. I would like to know if there is another test to confirm the stationarity. Any advice?

Comment: Have you looked at http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-check-if-a-timeseries-is-stationary ?