# Test for stationarity and make use of non-stationary points in financial market?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-calculus, stationarity, financial-engineering

I have two questions to ask:

1. What are the best methods to determine stationarity in a financial market (such as stocks) using MATLAB?
2. What methods would you recommend to use in order to change from non-stationary points to stationary points (so as to better predict the market), so that I can use the resulted data for genetics algorithms or genetics programming to predict the next move?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: See http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/183/what-is-a-stationary-process and http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-check-if-a-timeseries-is-stationary and perhaps more if you search some more.

Comment: This might help you in answering the second question: http://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/07/stationary.asp